# Laravel return view on middleWare

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

in laravel i'm trying to check user `active` column and if its `0` then must be show simple view as `your account is disable`, after implementing below codes i get this error:

[image: Call to a member function setCookie() on null]

my middleware:

```
class CheckUserActive
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            if (auth()->user()->active == 0) {
                auth()->logout();
                $message = 'your account is disable';
                return view('layouts.frontend.pages.user-messages', compact('message'));
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

`kernel.php`:

```
...
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ...
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserActive::class,

        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
...
```

`user-messages.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.frontend.main')

@section('content')
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p style="text-align: center;">
                                {!! $message !!}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use middleware to return a view, rather use it to redirect to a route and then return a view from your controller.

In your middleware:

```
use Auth;

class CheckUserActive
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if (Auth::User()->active == 0) {
                Auth::logout();
                return redirect()->route('redirect-route');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Create a new named route:

```
Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'redirect-route',
        'uses' => 'PageController@redirectFunction',
    ]);
```

Now create a function in your controller:

```
public function redirectFunction() 
{ 
    $message = 'your account is disable';
    return view('layouts.frontend.pages.user-messages', compact('message'));
}
```

Comment: now i get this error: `Call to undefined method App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserActive::auth()` and please say me whats problem

Comment: error:`Undefined property: App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserActive::$auth`

Comment: on this line `if ($this->auth->user()) {`

Comment: Updated the answer again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171315/discussion-between-mahdi-pishguy-and-saurabh).

Answer (score 26):

based on the documentation, you can access view using 
`response()->view('custom');`

Answer (score 18):

This one work for return view from middleware

```
return new response(view('view.path'));
```

EDIT: Yes, its worked without `new` keyword

```
return response(view('view.path'));
```

Comment: I managed to return a view without using the "new" keyword. However, I am curious as to what does it do?

Comment: This works without `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
use Auth;

class CheckUserActive
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if (Auth::user()->active == 0) {
                Auth::logout();
                $message = 'your account is disable';
                return view('layouts.frontend.pages.user-messages', compact('message'));
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove:

```
$response->header->setCookie(...);
```

and modify with:

```
$response->withCookie(..your cookie here...);
```

Have a look to this [post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-a-cookie-with-laravel-5)