# Call to a member function setCookie() on null on laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I made a custom route middleware to check if my user has enough privileges to see a page, when user doesn't have enough privileges I get the following error message:

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function setCookie() on null
```

This is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;


use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;



class AuthAdmin
{


    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user && $user['privileges'] > 2){
            return $next($request);   
        }

        return view('auth.login');

    }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function setCookie() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970172/call-to-a-member-function-setcookie-on-null)

Comment: Don't return a view from middleware, return a redirect response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408698/laravel-return-view-on-middleware

Answer (score 0):

try

`return response()->view('auth.login');`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `return view('Somepage')` try `return redirect('some route')`